# How to Prevent Sleep Mode when CPU usage is over ___%

Tags: cpu, sleep

I render animations overnight, but I don't want my computer to be on when its done, so how would I do this?

Comment: You can help others, not me, to help you by telling what application(s) you use to do the rendering. Perhaps, instead of measuring CPU usage, by monitoring the application itself one can find a solution to prevent sleep. Isn't there a preference option or a (3rd party) plugin for this, by the way? Good luck.

Comment: So you are trying to keep it awake until the rendering is complete and then shut it down or put it to sleep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use program called [Airytec Switch Off](http://www.airytec.com/en/switch-off/) (I am not affiliated with a program).
First you set you PC not to go to sleep in Windows
(Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Power Options) and then set Airytec Switch Off. 
You can shutdown your computer after some time of the CPU inactivity (idle) by right click on tray icon then shutdown/sleep - past 5 minutes - of computer inactivity.
For Mac OS X read [this link](https://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2011-04-14-how-to-make-your-mac-sleep-after-inactivity/).
Also next time specify the operating system you are using when asking a question.

Comment: Thank You. haven't tested it yet, but it looks like it will work. Sorry for not including OS.